# How does Clojure produce a positive value when a negative value is passed to this abs function?

Tags: clojure, scheme, sicp

It has been nagging me as to how cond returns a positive value in function, when a negative value is passed to its x parameter. My idea is that two negatives multiplied produce a positive, but this seems quite confusing as there appears to be no multiplication occurring anywhere in the function.

Could someone give me an detailed explanation of why a negative value passed to x returns a positive value?

```
(def abs
   (fn [x]
      (cond (> x 0) x
            (= x 0) 0 
            (< x 0) (- x))))

(abs -10) -> 10
```

The code is a variation of the abs function found in the book SICP, but written in Clojure.

Kind regards

Comment: FYI, Clojure has neg?, pos? and zero? functions.  Also, you can use Java interop to call Math/abs.  For example, (Math/abs -10) returns 10.

Comment: Be aware that Math/abs doesn't work for all numerical types in the Clojure numerical tower.

Comment: The closing parenthesis on line 3 should be moved to the end. Edit to fix? This appears to be a typo rather than related to your question.

Comment: You comment that *two negatives multiplied produce a positive, but ... there appears to be no multiplication*. Multiplication is not the only way to convert a negative number into a positive one. The function `(defn - ([x] ...))` *always* turns a negative number into a positive one - and vice versa - without multiplication.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the number is negative, `(< x 0)`, we negate it, `(- x)`, to get a positive number of the same magnitude. You can think of negation as multiplication by -1 if you like.

```
(doc -)
-------------------------
clojure.core/-
([x] [x y] [x y & more])
  If no ys are supplied, returns the negation of x, else ...
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out with these n-ary functions that `+` and `*` are conceptually simpler.  Since `+` and `*` are commutative and have an identity element, it's easy to say `(+) == 0`, `(+ x) == x` and `(+ x y) == x+y`.  Similarly `(*) == 1`, `(* x) = x`, and `(* x y) == xy`.  Subtraction and division aren't commutative though.  That means there's no real sensible value for `(-)` or `(/)`, but at least with `(- x)` and `(/ x)`, returning the inverse of `x` with respect to `+` and `*` is useful.